# Polar limits approaching $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let's say I have $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$, and I want to know if $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$$ exists.

Suppose I substitute $x$ and $y$ for their polar forms $r\cos(\theta )$, $r\sin(\theta )$. Then, when analysing $\lim_{r \to 0} f(r, \theta)$, I get some $\theta$-dependent trigonometric function (e.g. $1-2\sin(\theta)$).

Is this enough proof to say that the limit does not exist?

My idea was that when approaching through different angles, the limit would tend to different values, thus it does not exist. I don't know if this logic is valid, though.

Thanks!

Comment: Your logic is correct.